# How do you mount volumes on Dask workers with dask-kubernetes?

Tags: azure-storage-files, dask-kubernetes

I used the following code to create a cluster

```yaml
from dask_kubernetes import KubeCluster
cluster = KubeCluster.from_yaml('worker.yaml')
cluster.adapt(minimum=1, maximum=10)
```

with the following yaml code (`worker.yaml`):

```yaml
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    foo: bar
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - image: daskdev/dask:latest
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    args: [dask-worker, --nthreads, '4', --no-bokeh, --memory-limit,  3GB, --death-timeout, '300']
    name: dask
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: "4"
        memory: 3G
      requests:
        cpu: "2"
        memory: 2G
```

This worked as expected.  Now I added a volume mount as shown

```yaml
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    foo: bar
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - image: daskdev/dask:latest
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    args: [dask-worker, --nthreads, '4', --no-bokeh, --memory-limit,  3GB, --death-timeout, '300']
    name: dask
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: "4"
        memory: 3G
      requests:
        cpu: "2"
        memory: 2G
    volumeMounts:
    - name: somedata
      mountPath: /opt/some/data
  volumes:
  - name: somedata
    azureFile:
      secretName: azure-secret
      shareName: somedata
      readOnly: true
```

I don't see the volume getting mounted.  But when I simply run

```sh
kubectl create -f worker.yaml
```

I can see the volume getting mounted.

Does `KubeCluster` support volume mounts? And if so how do you configure them?

Comment: where you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce your issue when testing with a `HostPath` volume.

```py
from dask_kubernetes import KubeCluster
cluster = KubeCluster.from_yaml('worker.yaml')
cluster.adapt(minimum=1, maximum=10)
```

```yaml
# worker.yaml
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    foo: bar
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - image: daskdev/dask:latest
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    args: [dask-worker, --nthreads, '4', --no-bokeh, --memory-limit,  3GB, --death-timeout, '300']
    name: dask
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: "4"
        memory: 3G
      requests:
        cpu: "2"
        memory: 2G
    volumeMounts:
    - name: somedata
      mountPath: /opt/some/data
  volumes:
  - name: somedata
    hostPath:
      path: /tmp/data
      type: Directory
```

If I run `kubectl describe po <podname>` for the worker that is created I can see the volume created successfully.

```
Volumes:
  somedata:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /tmp/data
    HostPathType:  Directory
```

And it is mounted where I would expect.

```
    Mounts:
      /opt/some/data from somedata (rw)
```

Also if I create a shell into the container with `kubectl exec -it <podname> bash` and `ls /opt/some/data` I can see files that I create in the host path.

Therefore volumes work with `KubeCluster`, so if you are experiencing issues with the `azureFile` storage then there must be some configuration issue with your Kubernetes cluster.